# Resizing html Checkboxes for pdf output

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Here's the pickle. To resize checkboxes in html, it is usually recommended that you utilize js to force the browser to resize the elements.

However, in our case, we are using wkhtmltopdf (a command line converter that utilizes webkit to create the html output that is then converted into PDF,) which to my knowledge, does not execute js.

In this context we still need to shrink down some checkboxes and radio buttons (actually, 'some' is wrong - a whole heck of a lot of them!)

What is a possible method for doing this, and if there is more than one, the best practice?

Comment: I disagree that the recommended method for sizing webpage checkboxes is JavaScript. CSS was designed precisely for controlling the appearance of web elements. If you have all your HTML files using one single style sheet, then you can just made the CSS changes in that one single stylesheet.

Comment: Disagree if you'd like, but every place I see the problem being tackled the recommendation is to use javascript! It's not right according to the ideal by which css was fashioned, but consider that the visual assets (checkboxes and radios) are provided by the browser. That complicates things a bit!

Comment: I would love to have a look at your HTML / JS / CSS.

Comment: Nope. Our final solution was to create svg images. resizing via css is too inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is pretty old thread, but I had the same problem and did not find a proper answer anywhere so I wanted to help other people with similar problem. I was dealing with size of checkboxes in generated pdf by mdpf. Only thing that worked was font-size. Try something like:

```
<input type='checkbox' style='font-size: 20pt;'>
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Just had a similar problem with mpdf. This is the correct answer - but beware: you have to set a class="xy" to the input element. It seems that input[type=checkbox] will not work for mpdf. So use .xy{font-size: 20pt;}

Comment: Neither Brabino nor @Rene's solution worked for me.  Although the checkbox does have more whitespace around it as though the padding or margin increased, the checkbox itself is the same size as before.  I'm using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a print stylesheet to see if it affects the output?

```
@media print { /* css code */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS to change their size? This works fine in Chrome which is a webkit based browser.

```
input.big{
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

input.small{
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 0.5em;    
}

<input type="checkbox" id="small" class="small"/><label for="small">Small</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="big" class="big"/><label for="big">Big</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8AzW/

Comment: it doesn't really work. While it does use webkit, precisely the results of these kind of tweaks is somewhat undefined...

Comment: It's also worth noting wkhtmltopdf, in rendering checkboxes and radios, uses an svg image (since as you might recall the graphics are normally produced by the browser and wkhtmltopdf is Webkit but not an actual browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Style pt changes to font-size did not work for my output.  But there is a PDF property 'transform' that worked.  You can use decimal points too.  1.5 worked best, while 2 made the radio-button or checkbox too large.

```
$"<input style=\"transform: scale(1.5);\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{q.Id}\" data-pdf-form-field=\"true\" name=\"foobar\" {check}>"
```